# Why can I only see the prototype of the constructor function?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, instance

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype = {
  constructor: Dog,
  age: 16,
  eat: function() {
    console.log('this function works')
  }
}

let beagle = new Dog("Snoopy");

console.log(Dog.prototype);
console.log(beagle.prototype);
beagle.eat();
```

The console outputs the prototype for the constructor function, but returns undefined for the prototype of the beagle. If I call eat() on the beagle however, it outputs 'This function works'. Why is the prototype undefined, despite the fact that I can still call the function eat() on the beagle object?

Comment: Try `Object.assign(Dog.prototype, dogPrototype);` instead of `Dog.prototype = {`? And use `Object.getPrototypeOf(beagle)` to get the prototype of the beagle object

Comment: @evolutionxbox, this worked; thanks! I'd like to understand why I can't simply get the prototype using .prototype alone. Does this work like getters and setters where we have private variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Prototype` is the **property of the constructor function**, so that's why `beagle` don't have `beagle.prototype` as a property but all ordinary objects in JavaScript have an internal prototype slot which is not a `.prototype` property but `__proto__` and you can access it with `.__proto__` like this:

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Dog.prototype = {
  constructor: Dog,
  age: 16,
  eat: function() {
    console.log('this function works')
  }
}

let beagle = new Dog("Snoopy");

console.log(Dog.prototype);
console.log(beagle.__proto__);
beagle.eat();
```

Comment: Thank you; this made a lot of sense and it returned what I expected it to. I assure you that I knew nothing about  .__proto__

Comment: happy to help, have a great time.

Comment: @Aren don't use `__proto__`, use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead

Comment: @evolutionxbox, it's because Object.getPrototypeOf is read-only right?

Comment: @Aren it’s because `__proto__` is deprecated and shouldn’t be relied upon

Comment: Yes @ Aren, @evolutionxbox  is absolutely right, using this is bad practice because the use of It was never originally included in the ECMAScript language spec, but modern browsers implemented it anyway. Its semantics are standardized for compatibility with web browsers, so it will be supported into the future — nevertheless, it is deprecated in favor of Object.getPrototypeOf.